# mean.io console errors mac Sierra

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean.io

After having installed mean.io, I get a bloated console when starting http://localhost:3000/:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $http.get(...).success is not a function
    at new MeanUserKlass (meanUser.js:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (meanUser.js:103)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4839)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4673)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4839)
    at angular.js:4633
    at getService (angular.js:4780)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4805)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4831)
    at angular.js:4642
4angular.js:14324Possibly unhandled rejection: {}
```

I am wondering why these errors on a fresh install..?

node version : v6.9.2 
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Changing ".success" to ".then" solved the problem.